# $a=\frac{2}{3}b+\frac{1}{3}c$ as Average Value

Tags: integration, functions

$f(x)$ is a continuous function and a is the average value of f on the interval [1, 4]. b is the average value of f on the interval [1,3]. c is the average value of f on [3, 4]. Is it true that $a=\frac{2}{3}b+\frac{1}{3}c$? I hypothesize this to be false. For a continuous function, say sinx, the average value over these ranges does not form this equation here. But I wanted a formal mathematical proof for this. Where do I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $$a = \frac{1}{4-1} \int_{x=1}^4 f(x) \, dx, \\ b = \frac{1}{1-3} \int_{x=1}^3 f(x) \, dx, \\ c = \frac{1}{4-3} \int_{x=3}^4 f(x) \, dx.$$  Consequently $$3a = \int_{x=1}^4 f(x) \, dx = \int_{x=1}^3 f(x) \, dx + \int_{x=3}^4 f(x) \, dx = 2b + c,$$ or $$a = \frac{2}{3} b + \frac{1}{3} c.$$  This applies as long as each of the individual integrals is well-defined.

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle 3a = \int_{1}^4 f(x) \text{d}(x)$, $\;\;\displaystyle 2b = \int_{1}^3 f(x) \text{d}(x) $, $\;\;\displaystyle c = \int_{3}^4 f(x) \text{d}(x) $

$\implies 3a = 2b + c \iff a = \frac{2}{3}b + \frac{1}{3}c$

For $f(x) = \sin(x)$ we get to $5$s.f

$a = 0.39798$,  $b = 0.76515$,  $c = -0.33635$ and indeed

$3(0.39798) = 2(0.76515) + (-0.33635)$ (at least to 4.s.f or so)